# When I add slash in my api route, some css go wrong

Tags: css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using springboot and thymeleaf to develop some web pages,
when my RequestMapping is `@GetMapping("/edit")`, it works well,
but when I change it to `@GetMapping("service/editor")`,
the corresponding template go wrong,some css cannot show correctly, like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you attach the html operation which send this request ?

Comment: I just access it by "localhost:8080/editor" and "localhost:8080/service/editor".

Comment: in the end of the method is: return "editor", there is a file named editor.html in the template folder

Comment: there are some linked css and js in the html like this:
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="dep/reveal/css/reveal.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dep/reveal/css/theme/white.css" id="theme"/>

Comment: You need to share the directory structure of your project and also the editor.html. But an easier way to link CSS is to use `th:href="@{/reveal/css/reveal.css}"` assuming `reveal` folder is under `src/main/resources/static`